# Input box on mobile borders missing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble with the borders on my input boxes.  The borders show up fine on desktop (even sized down to mobile) but on a phone parts of the borders disappear.  Any ideas on how to fix this?
[Image of text box issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsTel.png)

[Image of text box issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbUu7.png)

[Image of text box issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ32I.png)

Comment: Can you please post the HTML and CSS exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: This is not an usual behaviour. Let's share the code snippet to replicate the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS to prevent things from displaying as less than 1 pixel:

```
input, textarea {
    transform: perspective(1px);
}
```